# How to read input variable from .ini and output to separet file?

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, exe

I have a Batch that runs 2 programs Example.exe and Log.exe

Log.exe reads from Example.exe and once Example.exe ends, Log.exe reads input and logs to (Test.ini) automatically

My goal is to read a string within Test.ini after the programs have been executed. We'll call the said string WIN

If WIN=1 I would like to output "WIN=1" to a text file "test.log"
If WIN=0 I would like to output "WIN=0" to same text file

Comment: `findstr /b "WIN=" test.ini > test.log`

Comment: No luck on this line :/

Comment: Show (the relevant part of) `test.ini`. Also, we need to see its very first line (copy it from the output of `type`!)